# figure out ip addresses of all the machines remotely?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have around 40 machines and I want to know what are their IP Address. One way is to login into those boxes and figure out their IP Address by using `ifconfig` command but is there any other simple way I can use to figure out that?

I can save all machines in a txt file like this and read it from shell script and then what I should do to figure out IP Addresses?

```
machineA
machineB
machineC
```

Comment: Does `host machineA` resolves IP? I mean are you using DNS or `/etc/hosts` file ?

Comment: In my text file I will have my actual machine name. `machineA` was just an example for demonstrating. After logging to each machine, I usually do `ifconfig` to figure out the ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DNS you can use tool like `host`, `nslookup`, `dig` to resolve the IP from hostnames.

You can use this one liner :

```
while IFS= read -r name; do host "$name"; done <hosts.txt
```

Also if you want to get only the IP addresses without the hostnames sequentially, you can use `grep` :

```
while IFS= read -r name; do host "$name" | grep -o '[[:digit:]][^ ]*$'; done <hosts.txt
```

Comment: Awesome, this works fantastic. Thanks for showing me this trick. Appreciated

Comment: @david Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

In one of your 40 systems, install this arp package

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
```

then run this  in that system:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

with this you can get all the ip's

1) execute it remotely
2) auto execute every 10 mins or so and then save it automatically to a text file

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you provide an example how can I execute this remotely?

Comment: Just login to that one machine in which you installed arp and in termial you can type the command which I gave "sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet". You can get ips of all machines